# Is there an elegant zip to interleave two lists in Perl 5?

Tags: perl, zip

I recently "needed" a zip function in Perl 5 (while I was thinking about [How do I calculate relative time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time)), i.e. a function that takes two lists and "zips" them together to one list, interleaving the elements.

(Pseudo)example:

```
@a=(1, 2, 3);
@b=('apple', 'orange', 'grape');
zip @a, @b; # (1, 'apple', 2, 'orange', 3, 'grape');
```

[Haskell has zip in the Prelude](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html) and [Perl 6 has a zip operator](http://ferreira.nfshost.com/perl6/zip.html) built in, but how do you do it in an elegant way in Perl 5?

Comment: Haskell's zip is not what you are looking for: it returns a list of corresponding pairs, not a list of interleaved elements.

Comment: You're right; Haskell lists contains elements if a single type. I wasn't thinking when I referred to Haskell here.

Comment: Often when one thinks they want a zip, it's to create a hash from two lists. In that case better to use a hash slice. `@hash{@keys} = @values`. If that's not the case here, then sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Assuming you have exactly two lists and they are exactly the same length, here is a solution originally by merlyn (Randal Schwartz), who called it perversely perlish:

```
sub zip2 {
    my $p = @_ / 2; 
    return @_[ map { $_, $_ + $p } 0 .. $p - 1 ];
}
```

What happens here is that for a 10-element list, first, we find the pivot point in the middle, in this case 5, and save it in `$p`. Then we make a list of indices up to that point, in this case 0 1 2 3 4. Next we use `map` to pair each index with another index that’s at the same distance from the pivot point as the first index is from the start, giving us (in this case) 0 5 1 6 2 7 3 8 4 9. Then we take a slice from `@_` using that as the list of indices. This means that if `'a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 3` is passed to `zip2`, it will return that list rearranged into `'a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3`.

This can be written in a single expression along ysth’s lines like so:

```
sub zip2 { @_[map { $_, $_ + @_/2 } 0..(@_/2 - 1)] }
```

Whether you’d want to use either variation depends on whether you can see yourself remembering how they work, but for me, it was a mind expander.

Answer (score 30):

The [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::MoreUtils) module has a zip/mesh function that should do the trick:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(zip);

my @numbers = (1, 2, 3);
my @fruit = ('apple', 'orange', 'grape');

my @zipped = zip @numbers, @fruit;
```

Here is the source of the mesh function:

```
sub mesh (\@\@;\@\@\@\@\@\@\@\@\@\@\@\@\@\@\@\@\@\@\@\@\@\@\@\@\@\@\@\@\@\@) {
    my $max = -1;
    $max < $#$_  &&  ($max = $#$_)  for @_;

    map { my $ix = $_; map $_->[$ix], @_; } 0..$max; 
}
```

Comment: What are those escaped at-signs?

Comment: Prototypes, saying it takes two to 32 array parameters and the sub will implicitly receive them as arrayrefs.

Comment: My eyes bleed! Isn't there some shortcut like \@{32} or something similiar?

Comment: @Roberto, no but that's simply a prototype hack, your eyes are bleeding for all the wrong reason.

Comment: That prototype hack means that L::MU's `zip` only works for actual array variables, not arbitrary lists. For instance, you can't invert an array with `my %hash = zip(@ary, [0..$#ary])`; you have to make an array variable containing the indexes first.

Comment: but 7 years later, it's still not in the core distribution :(

Comment: arrayrefs just need to be dereferenced: ```my %hash = zip(@ary, @{[0..$#ary]});```

Answer (score 14):

I find the following solution straightforward and easy to read:

```
@a = (1, 2, 3);
@b = ('apple', 'orange', 'grape');
@zipped = map {($a[$_], $b[$_])} (0 .. $#a);
```

I believe it's also faster than solutions that create the array in a wrong order first and then use slice to reorder, or solutions that modify `@a` and `@b`.

Comment: This has problems for unequally-sized arrays.

Comment: @briandfoy your comments help, but you know what you forgot to do? point out which one *does* work for unequally-sized arrays. (I'm shopping for one that needs to do this)

Comment: I didn't forget. That problem depends on what you want to do with the remaining elements. You should ask a different question and specify your constraints.

Answer (score 11):

For arrays of the same length:

```
my @zipped = ( @a, @b )[ map { $_, $_ + @a } ( 0 .. $#a ) ];
```

Comment: This has problems for unequally-sized arrays.

Answer (score 4):

```
my @l1 = qw/1 2 3/;
my @l2 = qw/7 8 9/;
my @out; 
push @out, shift @l1, shift @l2 while ( @l1 || @l2 );
```

If the lists are a different length, this will put 'undef' in the extra slots but you can easily remedy this if you don't wish to do this. Something like ( @l1[0] && shift @l1 ) would do it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice solution, I should probably have expressed my preference for not modifying the two input-lists :-)

Answer (score 2):

[`Algorithm::Loops`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Algorithm::Loops) is really nice if you do much of this kind of thing.

My own code:

```
sub zip { @_[map $_&1 ? $_>>1 : ($_>>1)+($#_>>1), 1..@_] }
```

Comment: Using bit shifts might be faster in C but is just unnecessary obfuscation in Perl. Better written like so:

@_[ map { $_, $_ + @_/2 } 0 .. ( @_/2 - 1 ) ]

Shorter, too.

Comment: It isn't an issue for the question here, but my zip was designed to work for odd numbers of elements too.

Answer (score 1):

This is totally not an elegant solution, nor is it the best solution by any stretch of the imagination.  But it's fun!

```
package zip;

sub TIEARRAY {
    my ($class, @self) = @_;
    bless \@self, $class;
}

sub FETCH {
    my ($self, $index) = @_;
    $self->[$index % @$self][$index / @$self];
}

sub STORE {
    my ($self, $index, $value) = @_;
    $self->[$index % @$self][$index / @$self] = $value;
}

sub FETCHSIZE {
    my ($self) = @_;
    my $size = 0;
    @$_ > $size and $size = @$_ for @$self;
    $size * @$self;
}

sub CLEAR {
    my ($self) = @_;
    @$_ = () for @$self;
}

package main;

my @a = qw(a b c d e f g);
my @b = 1 .. 7;

tie my @c, zip => \@a, \@b;

print "@c\n";  # ==> a 1 b 2 c 3 d 4 e 5 f 6 g 7
```

How to handle `STORESIZE`/`PUSH`/`POP`/`SHIFT`/`UNSHIFT`/`SPLICE` is an exercise left to the reader.