# How do I initialize HoH from arrays of variable size

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I need help figuring out how to accomodate situations in which $hash {$i} is loaded with @headers array of different sizes. 
        use strict;
        use warnings;

```
    my $file = "list.csv";

    open (FILE,"$file") || die "Can't open file: $!\n"; 
    my (@lines) = <FILE>; 
    close(FILE);

    my @headers = split(',',$lines[0]);#split up header line

    my %hash;
    for (my $i=1; $i < scalar(@lines); $i++)
    {
        my @strings = split(',',$lines[$i];

# NEED help here
        $hash{$i} = {
            $headers[0] => $strings[0],
            $headers[1] => $strings[0],
            $headers[2] => $strings[0],
            $headers[3] => $strings[0],
            $headers[4] => $strings[0],
            $headers[5] => $strings[0]
            };

    }
```

Is there a way to load up hash at index for in situations when scalar(@headers)=5,6,7 ... etc? Is there a programatic equivalent for something like...

```
$hash{$i} = {
        $headers[0] => $strings[0],
              ...
        $headers[n] => $strings[n]
        };
```

or

```
$hash{$i} = {@headers => @strings);
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38345/is-there-an-elegant-zip-to-interleave-two-lists-in-perl-5 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715957/how-can-i-assign-two-arrays-to-a-hash-in-perl/3715993#3715993

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idiom you want is:

```
@{ $hash{$i} }{ @headers } = @strings;
```

This is known as [slicing](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices).

Given that you're reading CSV data you might look at some of the CPAN modules out there for this sort of thing, [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV), for example.

Comment: +1 - always use CPAN - you do NOT want the headache of **correctly** parsing CSV files. Ever.

Answer (score 1):

[TIMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = "list.csv";

# Use lexical filehandles, not globals; use 3-arg open; don't quote filename
open ( my $fh, '<', $file ) or die "Can't open file: $!\n";
my( @lines ) = <$fh>;
close( $fh );

# split takes a regex; also, notice the shift
my @headers = split( /,/, shift @lines );

my %hash;

# Use perly for loops here
foreach my $i ( 0..$#lines )
# This works, too
#for my $i ( 0..$#lines )
{
    # split takes a regex
    my @strings = split( /,/, $lines[$i] );

    # One way (probably best)
    @{ $hash{$i} }{ @headers } = @strings;
    # Another way
    #$hash{$i} = { map { $headers[$_] => $strings[$_] } ( 0 .. $#strings ) };
    # Another way
    #$hash{$i}{ $headers[$_] } = $strings[$_] = for(0..$#strings);

}

#use Data::Dumper;
#print Dumper \%hash;
```

But yes, using [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV) (or the faster [Text::CSV_XS](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV_XS)) would be even better than trying to manually split the CSV yourself (what happens if there are spaces?  what happens if the fields and/or headers are quoted?  It's a solved problem.)