# How can I create an association list from 2 lists?

Tags: scheme, racket

In DrScheme, how can I create an association list from 2 lists?

For example, I have,

```
y = ( 1 2 3 )
x = ( a b c )
```

and I want

```
z = ((a 1) (b 2) (c 3))
```

Comment: What language do you want to do this in?

Comment: ok guys, i'm tagging this as code golf... :)

Comment: why was the code-golf tag added?

Comment: @littlegreen: `[code-golf]` has a specific rule. You mean `[language-agnostic]`?

Comment: Because this isn't officially code golf, but it's really starting to look like it since nobody knows which language the OP wants it in :)

Comment: @KennyTM: Yes, technically you are correct.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming Scheme (since your last 2 questions are on Scheme):

```
(define x '(1 2 3))
(define y '(4 5 6))
(define (zip p q) (map list p q))  ;; <----
(display (zip x y))
;; ((1 4) (2 5) (3 6))
```

Result: http://www.ideone.com/DPjeM

Comment: You have an unnecessary apply and list in your solution.  (define (zip p q) (map list p q))

Answer (score 4):

In C# 4.0 you can do it this way;

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList<int>();
var abcs = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J" };

var newList = abcs.Zip(numbers, (abc, number) => string.Format("({0} {1})", abc, number));

foreach (var i in newList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

In [Python](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) it's pretty easy, just `zip(x,y)`. If you want an associative dictionary from it:

```
z = dict(zip(x,y))
```

.

```
>>> x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> y = [1,2,3]
>>> z = dict(zip(x,y))
>>> z
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP has [array_combine()](https://www.php.net/array_combine).

e.g. from the manual:

```
$a = array('green', 'red', 'yellow');
$b = array('avocado', 'apple', 'banana');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);
```

Answer (score 1):

;; generalized zip for many lists

#### (define (zip xs) (apply map list xs))

```
 > test
 '((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9))
 > (zip test)
 '((1 4 7) (2 5 8) (3 6 9))
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the language you're using there maty exist a "zip" function that does this, see this stackoverflow question:  [zip to interleave two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38345/is-there-an-elegant-zip-to-interleave-two-lists-in-perl-5)

Answer (score 0):

And perl:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw/pairwise/;
use Data::Dumper;

my @a = (1,2,3,4);
my @b = (5,6,7,8);

my @c = pairwise { [$a, $b] } @a, @b;
print Dumper(\@c);
```

Also for the sake of illustrating how this is done in q. ([kdb+/q](http://kx.com/Products/kdb+.php))

```
q)flip (enlist til 10),(enlist 10?10)
0 8
1 1
2 7
3 2
4 4
5 5
6 4
7 2
8 7
9 8
```