# Scheme combining two lists in a certain way

Tags: scheme, lisp

This is my second question in Scheme. Say I have 2 lists

```
'("a" "b" "c")

'("e" "f" "g")
```

I want to combine them in this way:

```
'(("a" "e") ("b" "f") ("c" "g"))
```

Is this possible?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078678/how-can-i-create-an-association-list-from-2-lists

Answer (score 1):

You use [SRFI-1 List library](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html). the function name is `zip`. When you `apply` `zip` to a `zip` result you're back to where you started so `unzip` is usually the same procedure except it takes a list of lists instead of many list arguments.

```
(zip '(1 2 3) '(a b c))         ; ==> ((1 a) (2 b) (3 c))
(unzip '((1 2 3) (a b c)))      ; ==> ((1 a) (2 b) (3 c))
(unzip '((1 a) (2 b) (3 c)))    ; ==> ((1 2 3) (a b c))
```

If you follow the link you'll find a reference implementation. However you usually don't need it as most implementations do include them. E.g. In Racket R6RS you `(import (srfi :1))` or in the racket language you `(require srfi/1)`. In Chicken you `(declare (uses srfi-1))` so the syntax between the implementations varies greatly.

You tagged `lisp` so for completeness a Common Lisp implementation would look like this:

```
(defun zip (&rest lsts)
  (apply #'mapcar #'list lsts)) 

(defun unzip (lsts)
  (apply #'mapcar #'list lsts))
```