# how to print an array in particular format in perl?

Tags: regex, arrays, algorithm, perl, perl-module

Can anyone tell me how to use 2 array together to print in a particular manner?

```
@array1= "in_1","in_2","in_3";

@array2= "1","0","1";
```

I want them to be printed in this pattern

```
in_1 = 1; in_2 = 0; in_3 =1 ;
```

thanks

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38345/is-there-an-elegant-zip-to-interleave-two-lists-in-perl-5 - the general task here is "zip", with the output being secondary.

Comment: Note: `@array1 = "in_1","in_2","in_3";` should be changed to `@array1 = ("in_1","in_2","in_3");` or similar .. otherwise it'll never work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print map "$array1[$_] = $array2[$_]; ", 0 .. $#array1;
```

Comment: this prints in_1 = 1;  = ; in_1 = 1;

Comment: @mayhem `@array1= "in_1","in_2","in_3";` should be `@array1 = ("in_1","in_2","in_3");` or `@array1 = qw/in_1 in_2 in_3/;` - otherwise you're not assigning a list!

Comment: @user2864740 could not agree more.

Answer (score 0):

Could use a hash slice (associative array)

```
@ary1 = (a,b,c);
@ary2 = (1,2,3);
%hash = ();
@hash{@ary1} = @ary2;

foreach $key ( keys %hash )
{
    print "$key = $hash{$key}\n";
}
```

Or just a simple loop.

```
for (0 .. $#ary1)
{
   print "$ary1[$_] = $ary2[$_]\n";
}
```

Comment: The hash order is not guaranteed. I would not recommend it for such tasks.