# Perl: array splitting and complex merging

Tags: arrays, perl, merge

I have the following string `A B C D E F G H I J`. I want to make an array out of it, so I use this

```
my @string = split/(\W)/, $text;
```

It works ok, and I get an array of 20 lines looking like this:

```
A

B

C

D

...
```

Now, I want to split this array in a given number of pieces (let's say 4 in this case), thus resulting I imagine in 4 smaller arrays of 5 lines each, looking like this @1 = `A, ,B, ,C` , @2 = `,D, ,E,`, @3 = `F, ,G, ,H` and @4 = `,I, ,J,`.
Finally, I want to interleave these 4 arrays in order to get an output array in which I first have the first line of each array, the the second line of each array, and so on... the final thing looking like this :

```
A

F


D

I
B

G


E

J
C

H
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Your `split` will add the whitespace intervals as separate elements. But you seem to know this, as you say `@1 = A, ,B, ,C` etc. It is very hard to believe that this is what you want, so please confirm.

Comment: Are you sure that what you need isn't a Perl tutorial? You seem to be stumbling over very basic concepts.

Comment: You have been directed towards the module `List::MoreUtils`, with its functions `zip/mesh` in your previous, identical question. That question was marked as a duplicate, because it was already answered. Posting the same question again will not accomplish anything. If you're having problems applying the suggested solution to your problem, ask a question about the code you have tried. That is what this site is for. Not for getting free code.

Comment: The linked question was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38345/is-there-an-elegant-zip-to-interleave-two-lists-in-perl-5

Comment: @TLP: If you are saying that this is a duplicate question then please mark it as such. Malevolent comments aren't useful.

Comment: @Borodin I already closed the previous question he posted, which was identical to this one. Apparently he needed more information, which is what I gave him. If you think that is malevolent, that is only in your own mind, and I encourage you to read my comment with an open mind. If I "mark" this question as a duplicate, it is immediately closed -- because of my previleges -- and I thought that it would be fair if I first gave him a chance to fix it.

Comment: You mentioned in a comment on your previous question that you tried the first solution in the linked duplicate, but it wasn't working for you. Please [edit] your question to include the code you tried, the output you got, and any errors. Or, as @TLP has mentioned several times, simply use the `zip` function from [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils)...that would probably be easier.

Comment: @ Borodin: yes I confirm. Maybe I need a tutorial in fact, I'm a beginner so...
@ TLP: Yes I have ask a new question because I was asked to do so by ThisSuitIsBlackNot in a comment on my previous question, and I was told to expose the exact code I was using, so here is the reason why I've posted this new question.

Comment: Ok I've used the `zip` function (which I didn't know of before) and it works perfect. Thank you all !

Comment: @chris202 Glad it worked for you. I'm sorry that the duplicate we linked to your first question wasn't helpful...unfortunately, the best and simplest answer (`zip` or `merge` from `List::MoreUtils`) is not the highest-voted answer to that question, and there was no example of how to use `zip` in the answer so I understand how you could have missed it (I've added a usage example to make it clearer). In the future, if your question is closed as a dupe, you may need to try several of the answers, not just the top one.

Comment: @chris202 As for tutorials: there are a lot of really old Perl tutorials floating around on the web that demonstrate horrible programming practices. I'd recommend one of [these modern Perl tutorials](http://perl-tutorial.org/#index3h1). Personally, I started with "Learn Perl in about 2 hours 30 minutes," but there are many good ones out there. Also, learn to love Perl's built-in documentation, `perldoc`. If installed on your system, you can run `perldoc perlvar` to learn about built-in variables, `perldoc perlop` to learn about operators, `perldoc -f <function>` (e.g. `perldoc -f sort`)

Comment: *(continued)* to learn about built-in functions, `perldoc Module::Name` (e.g. `perldoc List::MoreUtils`) to learn about installed modules, and much more. The documentation is fantastic and should be your #1 go-to resource for Perl questions (yes, even before Stack Overflow). Good luck!

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Thanks for all the good info, I'll definitely have a look at it !

Answer (score 0):

1. **To make a slice of an array in Perl:**

   ```
   my @oldArray = (a, ,b, ,c, ,d, ,e, ,f, ,g, h, ,i, ,j, );

   my @newArray1 = @oldArray[elemIndex1,elemIndex2,elemIndexN];
   ```

   OR

   ```
   my @newArray1 = @oldArray[firstElemIndex..lastElemIndex]
   ```

   Where `elemIndex` is the index of the element you want in the `newArray` array.

   `firstElemIndex..lastElemIndex` is used when you want consecutive indexes to be in the sliced array.
2. **To add elements at the end of an array:**

   ```
   push(@interleavedArray,$newArray1[elemIndex]);
   ```

   Where `$newArray1[elemIndex]` is the element from `@newArray1` you want to add to `@interleavedArray`
3. **To add elements in order:**

   Just do a for loop:

   ```
   for my $index (0..3){
       push(@interleavedArray,$newArray1[$index]);
       push(@interleavedArray,$newArray2[$index]);
       push(@interleavedArray,$newArray3[$index]);
       push(@interleavedArray,$newArray4[$index]);
       }
   ```